# Image file is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, file, c#-4.0, file-io

I want to delete my image from folder. But it throws "***it is being used by another process***."

Here is my code:

```
fuProductImage.SaveAs(fileFolderPathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName);

 Bitmap orgImage = new Bitmap(fileFolderPathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName);
 ResizeAndSaveImages(orgImage, fileFolderPathLarge, fuProductImage.FileName, 66, 66);

 File.Delete(fileFolderPathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName);
```

What should I do to delete this file?

Comment: Put some `using` around the line two: `using ( Bitmap orgImage = new Bitmap(fileFolderPathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName) ) { /* here line 3 only. */ }`.

Comment: @UweKeim thank you. It works very well. Can you write again as answer? Because so many people doesn't check nonanswered questions. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of request, my suggestion is to put line two and three into a [`using` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like:

```
fuProductImage.SaveAs(fileFolderPathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName);

using ( Bitmap orgImage = 
        new Bitmap(fileFolderPathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName) )
{
    ResizeAndSaveImages(
        orgImage, 
        fileFolderPathLarge, 
        fuProductImage.FileName, 
        66, 
        66);
}

File.Delete(fileFolderPathTemp + fuProductImage.FileName);
```

The reason why this should help is that the `using` ensures that the `orgImage` is correctly being [disposed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), thus freeing memory and releasing file handles before you call the `File.Delete()` function.